# Capturing NSLog in release mode

Tags: cocoa, macos, nslog

My Application, running fine in Release and debug mode as well, if i run thru XCode, 
but if i double click on Application, then its crashing at the same place, but i couldn’t able to proceeds, 
Is there any way to Capture the NSLog if i am running my application outside XCode environment, or any other pointer to analyze the crash.

Kind Regards
Rohan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDB, the apple debugger.

Just start the terminal and type in:

```
gdb -q path-to-your-application
```

When it has loaded press r in order to start your application.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

NSLog output goes to stdout, which goes to Console for applications launched from the Finder. In other words, look in Console.app.

Comment: NSLog sends to stderr. it would be horrible if stdout would be saved in the console.app ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could replace calls to `NSLog()` with calls to your own function that writes the output to a location that you specify, and optionally also calls `NSLog()` to dump the output to the console.